# Use underscore to replace object key from another object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using underscore, how can I replace each `data.type` key with its corresponding object from `example`.

For example, I have:

```
  var example = [
    {
      id: 1,
      data: {
        type: '/api/data/1/'
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      data: {
        type: '/api/data/2/'
      }
    },
  ];
```

And this:

```
  var data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      uri: '/api/data/1/'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      uri: '/api/data/2/'
    }
  ];
```

Would like to produce:

```
  var example = [
    {
      id: 1,
      data: {
        type: {
          id: 1,
          uri: '/api/data/1/'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      data: {
        type: {
          id: 2,
          uri: '/api/data/2/'
        }
      }
    },
  ];
```

Comment: is this a hw problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `for` loop if the items are sequential.

```
for(var i=0;i< example.length; i++) {
    example[i].data.type = data[i];
}

console.log(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like underscore have largely been replaced by features in newer versions of ECMAScript. If you want to modify the original array (per Sushanth's answer), use ES5's *forEach*:

```
example.forEach(function(v, i) {
  example[i].data.type = data[i];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(example));
```